# Would 'Google' be a synecdoche or a metonymy of the internet and technology?

Tags: rhetorical-devices, metonyms, synecdoche

I want to write an opening for my essay, but I'm not sure which term to use: metonymy or synecdoche. I have a feeling that it is a synecdoche because Google is a part of the Internet, but I would like confirmation.

Comment: Hello, Grace. Why don't you give two example sentences, showing an example of synecdoche and metonymy respectively, and say which seems closer to an example sentence with G/google?

Comment: Why use either word, especially since you’re not comfortable with either one? They are technical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 'Google' to stand for **all** electronic activity, or for the entire net, that is definitely *synecdoche.*

"Google was invented by Berners."
"Google transforms lives in Africa through mail, education, business, and economies of infrastructure."

If you are using 'Google' to stand for a business using the net that would be *metonomy*.

There is, as you have realised, much overlap.

Comment: Those example sentences don't seem like synecdoche or metonymy to me. The first instance describes a specific search engine only, leaving the the inference of the whole to come from "and all that". The second instance describes the activities of a particular company. Neither one really calls to mind any other internet activity, it's not clear that Google is being used to describe anything other than Google itself here.

Comment: Who is "Berners"?

Comment: I can't accept this as a good answer, since you haven't provided definitions of the words *synecdoche* or *metonomy* (and possibly additional arguments) that would support your conclusion. As it stands, the answer only provides an unsubstantiated personal opinion.